# Error in Vaadin project when upgrading from 22.0.2 to 22.1.0 version

Tags: java, vaadin

I have tried to upgrade my Vaadin version from 22.0.2 to 22.1.0 in order to solve this vulnerability:

https://vaadin.com/security/cve-2023-25499?utm_campaign=Vaadin%20Security%20Advisories&utm_medium=email&_hsmi=263537165&_hsenc=p2ANqtz-_okTMU7vlUb8lpc_UF0qnQ586WYzHfDWUQmpJcsbLmzjUrUBkVugEYeUTPuKQE9gjJxp_pgn-8pz0u84xpumm7lEO9Cg&utm_content=263537165&utm_source=hs_email

But when I compile the project whith maven compile I get this message:

[INFO] Opening system browser to validate license. If the browser is not opened, please open https://vaadin.com/pro/validate-license?connect=76ed2a34-0e7d-4371-a8fe-18088ed1636e&product
Name=flow&productVersion=9.1.2 manually
[INFO] For CI/CD build servers, you need to download a server license key, which can only be used for production builds. You can download a server license key from https://vaadin.com/my
account/licenses.
If you are working offline in development mode, please visit https://vaadin.com/pro/validate-license?getOfflineKey=mid-785f5586-288733d9 for an offline development mode license.

...

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:22.1.0:build-frontend (build-frontend) on project proyecto-app: Execution build-frontend of goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-p
lugin:22.1.0:build-frontend failed: Unable to validate the license, please check your internet connection. If you need to work offline then please go to https://vaadin.com/pro/validate-
license?getOfflineKey=mid-785f5586-288733d9 to retrieve an offline key.
[ERROR] For CI/CD build servers, you need to download a server license key, which can work offline to create production builds. You can download a server license key from https://vaadin
.com/myaccount/licenses.

I don't use any commercial feature, in fact the previous version works without any problem.
Why does this new version fails when I haven't change any code? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vaadin 22.1 is a commercial feature in itself, as described in the release notes.

Vaadin 22 was originally supposed to follow the same scheme as Vaadin versions 15 - 21 to only be maintained for a couple of months until the next major version was released. It was realized that some users were stuck on Vaadin 22 because the minimum required Java version was increased in Vaadin 23. For this reason, the maintenance duration for Vaadin 22 was extended by 12 months to give users time to upgrade. Those 12 additional months have now passed and free maintenance has ended.

Comment: Thanks for the information I will upgrade to 23

Comment: @jruizj74 I would recommend that you look at upgrading to Vaadin 24 soon as well since free maintenance for 23 ends in less than a year whereas Vaadin 24 remains maintained indefinitely until Vaadin 25 eventually becomes a thing.

Answer (score 4):

The error states, that you have not installed your license.

> Unable to validate the license, please check your internet connection. If you need to work offline then please go to https://vaadin.com/pro/validate- license?

22 is no longer supported for free (ended March 23). If you have a license,
install it - if not, update to 23, which is the current free LTS.

> Vaadin 22 is the latest stable version to support Java 8, and will be
> exceptionally maintained for an extra year, until **March 2023**, to help
> transition to Java 11. **Prime customers will get support until Match [sic] 2024**.
>
> ---
>
> Source: https://vaadin.com/releases/

Comment: Thanks for the information I will upgrade to 23